# Typing of async return different than expected

Tags: typescript

I have the following Typescript async function:

```
async function processState(state: keyof typeof STATES, errors: any[]) {
  const api = new GetStateInfo().setState(state);
  const result: StateInfo = await api
    .getContent()
    .catch(err => errors.push({ state, err }));

  return db().set<StateInfo>(`/reference/state/${state}`, result.mapped);
}
```

But I am struggling to understand why the type of `result` would vary from the de-promisified type of the async functions return type:

[image]

As you'd expect the return type of `.getContent()` is a Promise because it is an async function:

[image]

But for reasons that I am not grasping, the actual response coming back to the `result` variable is either the expected result or a number?

[image]

Can anyone help me understand where the possibility of a numeric response is coming from?

Comment: You can cast the response to the desired type in order to suppress the type error. As to why the result can be a number, I have no idea because you haven't provided any information about who wrote the code - a colleague or an external library author.

Comment: The code is all written by me but wasn't sure it was relevant since my question is about variance between the return type stated above and variable the return type is saved to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the catch block returns a numeric value from `Array.push`.

Either `api.getContent` is resolved or an error is thrown, but because your arrow function returns a number the result can be either `IApiResponse` or `number`.